# Why fread() is not getting the expected bytes?

Tags: c, file, null, fread

I'm trying to read file in binary mode using C, but it only stores in the buffer the first 43 characters.
I want to read the file in groups of 245 bytes. It contains multi-character bytes and also null chars.
This is the content of the file in hex:

```
323031353037303735393036333130343739332032373231333732534e30323033323545533036303130340000000008557c0000000000693c0000000000000c0000000008557c0000000000693c0000000000000c0000000008557c0000000000693c0000000000000c00001c00001c00001c00000c00000c00000c00001c4d4e202020204942202020204f393920202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202039444b524d4144
```

And this is the code that I have:

```
char* to_hex(const char* strin) {
    char * strout = malloc(2 * strlen(strin) + 1);
    int x;

    for (x = 0; x < strlen(strin);x++){
        sprintf(&strout[x+x],"%02x", (int)(*(unsigned char*)(&strin[x])) );
    }

    strout[2 * strlen(strin)]='\0'
    return strout;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE * pfinput = fopen("stack.bin", "rb");
    int lrec = 245;
    char* sbuff = (char *)malloc((lrec + 1) * sizeof(char));

    if (pfinput != NULL) {
        while (fread (sbuff, 1, lrec, pfinput) > 0){
            sbuff[lrec] = '\0';

            printf("len=%d hex=%s\n\n", strlen(sbuff), to_hex(sbuff) );

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It returns the following:

```
len=43 hex=323031353037303735393036333130343739332032373231333732534e3032303332354553303630313034
```

> Why it only reads 43 characters instead of 245?
>   Do you have any alternative to do it?

Comment: ' It contains multicharacter bytes and also null chars.' - surely, you realized that strlen() was useless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your string has embedded null characters, you cannot use `strlen` to reliably compute the number of characters. You need to capture the number of characters read by `fread` and use it.

```
int nread = 0;
while (( nread = fread (sbuff, 1, lrec, pfinput)) > 0)
```

Instead of

```
printf("len=%d hex=%s\n\n", strlen(sbuff), to_hex(sbuff) );
```

You need to use:

```
printf("len=%d hex=%s\n\n", nread, to_hex(sbuff) );
```

You'll also need to pass `nread` to `to_hex` so that you are able to treat the embedded null characters appropriately in that function.

```
char* to_hex(const char* strin, int nread) {
    char * strout = malloc(2 * nread + 1);
    int x;

    for (x = 0; x < nread; x++){
        sprintf(&strout[x+x],"%02x", (int)(*(unsigned char*)(&strin[x])) );
    }

    strout[2 * nread]='\0';
    return strout;
}
```

After that, the `printf` line needs to be:

```
printf("len=%d hex=%s\n\n", nread, to_hex(sbuff, nread) );
```

**PS** Note that you are leaking memory here. Memory allocated by `to_hex` is used in the call to `printf` but after that it is not deallocated. You might want to capture that memory in a variable and deallocate it.

```
char* hexstring = to_hex(sbuff, nread);
printf("len=%d hex=%s\n\n", nread, hexstring);
free(hexstring);
```

Also, deallocate `sbuff` before returning from `main`.

```
free(sbuff);
```

**PS 2** I would simplify the line

```
        sprintf(&strout[x+x],"%02x", (int)(*(unsigned char*)(&strin[x])) );
```

to

```
        int c = strin[x];
        sprintf(&strout[x+x],"%02x", c );
```

Comment: No.   Just because you pass lrec does not mean that lrec chars get read.

Comment: Thank you @RSahu, one question: I also have to `free(sbuff)` in each loop?

Comment: @llamazing, no, only at the end of `main`. You can avoid that by using arrays whose sizes are defined at compile time since you are using a hard coded number anyway.

Answer (score 0):

'Upon successful completion, fread() shall return the number of elements successfully read',

The vaue returned by fread() is the ONLY way to determine how many bytes have been read into your buffer.  At the end of the file, it is possible that less than 'lrec' chars may be read.